# Implementation of .mp4 format and H.264 encoder in android

Tags: android, h.264, video-encoding

I have implemented recording of video in android.
Now I want that I can set the recorder video format to .mp4 and video encoder to H.264.

I came to know that H.264 support for Android starts from honeycomb.

But isn't there any way to implemet this in lower versions of Android 2.2/2.3?
Any tutorial/PDF/Links/Sample code will be of great help if possible.